# How do i get facebook album id from url?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Im trying to publish to an album on a facebook page (I can post to the wall no problem - i have all the permissions).

The Facebook graph API says the album id is the value of aid. But the url looks like: https://www.facebook.com/media/set/?set=a.531274833612778.1073741825.193687907371474&type=3

So what is the album id?

Comment: [Checking the details of the photo in the album via API](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=531274843612777%3Ffields%3Dalbum) gives you `531274833612778` as album id, so obviously it’s the first number after `set=a.` up until to the next dot. (But you should not rely on parsing such values from the URL, because it might change at some point, but rather look them up via the API.)

Comment: Maybe you should put your comment in an answer so it can be accepted and upvoted? :)

Answer (score 7):

For the sake of this question having an answer (I missed out [@CBroe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1427878/cbroe) comment the first time I landed here).

The album ID is the first number right between `a.` and the next following `.` (dot).

In this case: `531274833612778`